# Exception User-Unhandled :'Could not find file 'PATH\...\net5.0\fileName.txt'.'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, exception

[Adding new file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWvpe.png)

**1.Try adding a new file manually in visual studio, but something wrong.**

```
 Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead("TextFile1.txt");
```

[Exception User-Unhandled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEGFd.png)

I'm try to find in File Explorer, the file .txt have already existed.
What wrong with it ?

**2. Is it just a bug of the Visual studio tool?** I figured out that just go to File Explorer and create file .txt, then back to Solution and add existing file, everything will be absolutely find.

Comment: The added file wont be copied to the output directory by default. To get it copied right-click on the file in _Solution Explorer_ and choose _Properties_. Set the _Copy to Output Directory_ value according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks so much. I figured out the string path is wrong.